# Python Interpreters

Tags: python, ubuntu

So, I'm now using PyCharm on ubuntu 15.04 and I was trying to use kivy with it. No problem with that, but my former IDE was Spyder3.4 that came with the Anaconda3 package. 
As I use PyCharm, if I want to use any libraries that came with the anaconda package, I'm always tracing the interpreter in the ~/anaconda3/bin directory; but every time I use kivy, I must use the interpreter in my /bin directory (in the computer root).
Is there a way to transfer all of the anaconda packages to the root interpreter or install kivy on anaconda's interpreter?
The best for me would it be if all could be mixed into one python 3.4.3 interpreter.

Comment: Maybe setting up virtual environment  (venv) and additionally add it in your script? In pycharm windows it is in the settings>pyrhon interpreter>python interpreter

Comment: try `~/anaconda3/bin/pip install kivy` which will install kivy within the anaconda3 environment.